# C++ Conversion Error: invalid conversion from short int* to short int

Tags: c++

I got a conversion error and actually don't know how to fix it.

I have to use these structs and dont know how to access the Date struct right.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


struct Date {
 short year;
 short month;
 short day;
};

struct Stuff {
  Date birth;
};

struct ListElement {
  struct Stuff* person;          // Pointer to struct Stuff 
  struct ListElement* next;      // Pointer to the next Element
};

int main() {
 short birth_year;
 short birth_month;
 short birth_day;
 cin >> birth_year;
 cin >> birth_month;
 cin >> birth_day;


 ListElement* const start = new ListElement();
 ListElement* actual = start;

 actual->person = new Stuff();
 actual->person->birth.year = new short[sizeof(birth_year)]; // Conversion Error

delete start;
delete actual;
}
```

Error message from GCC:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:35:29: error: invalid conversion from 'short int*' to 'short int' [-fpermissive]
  actual->person->birth.year = new short[sizeof(birth_year)]; // Conversion Error
```

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: This code makes no sense.  Why are you trying to assign an array to a single `short`?

Comment: [Please read more thoroughly what your compiler tells you](http://ideone.com/poCJJk)! Your title is wrong. And you don't need the `new()` there BTW.

Comment: Added the error message from GCC for you. Please read it, you have a type-mismatch: `short int` != `short int*`! **Always compile with full warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and handle all warnings!**

Comment: `delete actual;` is also a bug, as you already deleted that pointer.   This program smells like "Java programmer tries C++"

Comment: Do you maybe have a question about **how to read** the error messages you get?  It seems like you're really getting stuck _there_, and you'll only keep getting stuck with each new error if you can't read them.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot allocate memory for `actual->person->birth.year`, as `birth.year` is not a pointer.

You can just use: `actual->person->birth.year = 2014;` or
`actual->person->birth.year = birth_year;`

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want to really do is this:

`actual->person->birth.year = birth_year;`

If I am wrong, then read the following:

You have in your struct:

`short year;`

but you trying to assign what new returns to `year`.

You should do that a `short* year;` and handle it dynamically (never forget to de-allocate it)!

Answer (score 1):

The `year` is a `short` which is a direct member of `Date`. That is, if you create a `Stuff` object, it contains `birth`, which contains `year`. These don't need to be manually allocated, which is what you're trying to do with `new short[sizeof(birth_year)]`. Instead, you should just assign it a value:

```
actual->person->birth.year = 1990;
```

The reason for your error is that `new ...` expressions return a pointer to the object they allocate. That means it's giving you a `short*`, which you are then trying to store in a `short` - that's not going to work.

Another problem you have is that `new` doesn't work like `malloc`. You just pass it how many objects you want, not how many bytes. If you want a single `short`, you just do `new short`. If you wanted an array of, say, two `short`s, you would do `new short[2]`. Remember that a dynamically allocated object needs to be `delete`d - in the case of a dynamically allocated array, you need to use `delete[]` to destroy it.